# Does the 99$ iOS developer license allow me to publish one app, or multiple?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently looking at the iOS developer license which costs 99$ per year. I however found it unclear wether this is for ONE app of if I can publish multiple apps (cost-free, except for the 99$) to the AppStore?

**Can I publish more then one app under the 99$ iOS developer license?** If yes; is there an extra fee?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can submit as many apps as you want, but only for 1 year. You have to pay this $99 subscription fee annually (or 299 if you proceed on behalf of an enterprise).

Answer (score 2):

You need just one enrolled account. you can develop - publish app as much as you want.

**1. Develop**

Develop your application with the iOS SDK and a wealth of technical resources in the iOS Dev Center.

**2. Test**

Test and debug your code on iPad, iPhone and iPod touch to finalize your applications.

**3. Distribute**
Test and debug your code on iPad, iPhone and iPod touch to finalize your applications.

The iOS Developer Program provides you with the ability to distribute your apps on the App Store. Offer your free or commercial apps to millions of iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch customers around the world. Extend the ability to generate revenue from your apps on the App Store with In-App Purchases, iAd rich media ads, volume purchases and more.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Answer (score 1):

YES you can publish more then one app under the **$99** IOS Developer License. There is no extra charge for uploading more apps. These links would help you 
 https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/
 https://developer.apple.com/appstore/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is **no limit** to the number of apps you can publish under the 99$ iOS developer license **for a year**.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish several thousand apps on one developer account, no extra charge.